# find the path param using regex in the url

Tags: java

what is the regular expression to find the path param from the url?

```
http://localhost:8080/domain/v1/809pA8
https://localhost:8080/domain/v1/809pA8
```

Want to retrieve the value(809pA8) from the above URL using regular expression, java is preferable.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Have you looked at alternative approaches based on simple String functions?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733

Comment: Could the url be http://localhost:8080/domain/v1/809pA8?arg1=val1, or http://localhost:8080/domain/v1/809pA8/articles?

Comment: user3157090, you have posted 49 questions, the majority of which have perfectly valid answers. You should concider going back and marking the best ones as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you do something like

```
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

If you *really* prefer regexps, you could do

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/([^/]+)$").matcher(url);

if (m.find())
    value = m.group(1);
```

Comment: prefer regular expression.

Comment: Why? This problem isn't really complicated enough to require regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/domain/v1/809pA8";
String value = String.valueOf(url.subSequence(url.lastIndexOf('/'), url.length()-1));
```

No need for regex here, I think.

EDIT: I'm sorry I made a mistake:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/domain/v1/809pA8";
    String value = String.valueOf(url.subSequence(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.length()));
```

See this code working here: https://ideone.com/E30ddC

Comment: This is wrong since the end index (second argument to subSequence) is exclusive. This solution misses the last character.

Comment: So, why use `CharSequence.subSequence` instead of `String.substring`? For `String.substring` the end index is optional (and you wouldn't have to use `String.valueOf`).

Comment: It's just a way of doing things, the answer before mine was about String substring, I think it's better to give another solution better than repeat the one given before.

Answer (score 0):

For your simple case, regex is an overkill, as others noted. But, if you have more cases and this is why you prefer regex, give Spring's [AntPathMatcher#extractUriTemplateVariables](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html#extractUriTemplateVariables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) a look, if you're using Spring. It's actually better equipped for extracting path variables than regex directly. [Here are some good examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.2.x/spring-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcherTests.java#L352).